# Find rank and nullity of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

> To find:
>   rank $A$ and nullity $A$ for
>   $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &0  &0 \\ 
> 0 &  0.5&-0.5 \\ 
>  0&-0.5  & 0.5
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   I know the nullity refers to the number of free variables in the matrix and the rank refers to the $dim(columnspace)$; where to from here?

Comment: Hint: Consider $A\mathbf x= \mathbf0$. Then $\mathbf x$ is in the nullspace. How many vectors does it take to span this nullspace? The number of vectors is the nullity, i.e. it's the dimension of the nullspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix has one linearly independent row (take the negative of the second to get the third) implying that the rank is 1 and the nullity is 2.

Answer (score 8):

More Generally.
First you are going to want to set this matrix up as an [Augmented Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix)
where $Ax=0$.

$1)$ To find the rank, simply put the Matrix in [REF or RREF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & 0.5 & -0.5 & 0 \\
0 & -0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \end{array}\right] \longrightarrow RREF \longrightarrow \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 0 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0.5 & -0.5 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right] $

Seeing that we only have one [leading variable](http://maths.ucd.ie/courses/math1200/algebra/algebranotes2-4.pdf) we can now say that the rank is 1.

$2)$ To find nullity of the matrix simply subtract the rank of our Matrix from the total number of columns.

So:

**Null (A)=3 - 1=2**

Hope this is helpful.